# Emacs windows, frames, server and clients: threads or processes?

Tags: process, emacs, thread

From http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/

> Emacs server
>
> Some people like to keep only a single **instance** of Emacs open and edit
>   all their files in there. Doing this has a few advantages:
>
> You can kill/yank text between buffers in the same **instance** of Emacs.
>   Emacs remembers argument histories (what commands you've used, what
>   files you've opened, terms you've searched for, etc.), but only within
>   each **instance**. If you have many customizations, starting new **instances**
>   of Emacs is slow. Alas, when you type emacs in a shell to edit a file
>   (or when $EDITOR is invoked by an external program), a new **instance** of
>   Emacs is started. You can avoid this by using emacsclient, which
>   instead opens a new **frame** connected to an existing **instance** of Emacs:
>
> In your existing **instance** of Emacs, type M-x server-start. Or add
>   (server-start) to your .emacs file to make it do that automatically at
>   startup. To edit a file, type emacsclient -t FILENAME at a prompt. You
>   can also change your $EDITOR to emacsclient -t if you're using
>   programs that automatically invoke $EDITOR. (emacsclient -t opens a
>   new **frame** on the terminal; alternatively, emacsclient -c opens a new X
>   **frame**.) When you're done editing, type C-x C-c, which closes the
>   **frame**.

1. By a "instance"  of Emacs, is it the same as an Emacs process, or a
   thread?
2. Are different buffers (or windows, or frames) under the same Emacs
   window different threads of the emacs process? (I guess so) So do
   they communicate via shared memory?
3. Are an Emacs server and its clients different processes, or the
   different threads of the same emacs process? (I guess not, but the
   quote same that a client is a frame of the server, and I guess a
   frame is just a thread of the same process)
4. Generally, in the server-client model of an application, do the
   server and the clients run as different processes or threads? Is the
   communication between the server and clients done by shared memory
   or inter-process communication?

Answer (score 3):

1. In this context, an "instance of Emacs" refers to a single process.
2. No, Emacs doesn't hold a thread for each open buffer. My current session has 129 open buffers (some 100 opened from files, the others being output buffers for certain subordinate processes - python, ruby, elixir interpreters, wanderlust folder and summary views, `flycheck-mode` syntax checkers, etc.) but only 3 active threads.
3. The main Emacs process is the server, and each `emacsclient` runs in its own process, communicating with the server over UNIX domain sockets. When the server receives a connection request from a client, it opens the requested file in a new buffer in a new window in the server's frame. `emacsclient` has the sole function of sending the requested file to the server, and waiting for the server to return once you're done editing the file's buffer.
4. Generally, clients and servers run as separate processes - there is no guarantee that client and server are on the same network, let alone the same machine. Some servers start a new thread to handle each incoming client connection (Apache can be built to do this, for example), but the client is a separate process possibly on another machine on the other side of the planet. And note that shared memory *is* a form of inter-process communication, as are, for example, UNIX domain sockets.